# youtube api returns copyright free videos as copyrighted

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

While using the Youtube API, I'm getting wrong results from the **licensedContent**. This is how I check it:

```
def videos_list_by_id(client, **kwargs):
    response = client.videos().list(
        **kwargs
    ).execute()
    return response['items'][0]['contentDetails']['licensedContent']
```

The problem seems not to be in the code anyways as it does return **False** for copyrighted videos, but it also does, sometimes, for copyright free ones. I know that because the videos I'm checking are uploaded by myself and I can see if they have any copyright issue.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a video that returns incorrectly?

Comment: @DaImTo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQ2C1GMOZ68 is an example of one